# Products list state not showing updated product when edited

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble getting my products list displaying the updated list. The product changes in the db but not on the page:

Products.jsx:

```js
export default class Products extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentMode: 'read',
      productId: null,
      products: []
    };
  }

  changeAppMode = (newMode, productId) => {
    this.setState({currentMode: newMode});
        if(productId !== undefined){
        this.setState({productId: productId});
    }
  }
  
  render() {

    var modeComponent =
      <ReadProductsComponent  changeAppMode={this.changeAppMode}  productId={this.state.productId}  />;

      switch(this.state.currentMode){
        case 'read':
            break;
        case 'update':
            modeComponent = <UpdateProductComponent productId={this.state.productId} changeAppMode={this.changeAppMode}/>;
        break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return (
      modeComponent
    )
  }
}
```

products list page:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import {GetData} from '../../services/GetData';
import ProductsTable from './product_table.component';
import TopActionsComponent from './top_actions.component';


// component that contains all the logic and other smaller components
// that form the Read Products view

export default class ReadProductsComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

          products: []
        };

    }

    componentWillMount() {
      console.log("componentWillMount",this.state);
 
        if(sessionStorage.getItem("userData")){
         this.getProducts();
        
        }
        else{
             
          sessionStorage.setItem("userData",'');
          sessionStorage.clear();
         this.setState({redirectToReferrer: true});
        }
    }

         


       getProducts() {
  
        let data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("userData"));
        this.setState({name:data.userData.name});
      
        
        if (data) {
             

        this._asyncRequest = GetData('../products/', 'Bearer ' + data.userData.token)
          .then(response => {
            //console.log('read response:  !!!! ' + JSON.stringify(response));
            this._asyncRequest = null;
            // create an array of Customers only with relevant data
            const newProducts = response.map(c => {
              return {
                id: c.id,
                name: c.prodName,
                description: c.description,
                buyPrice: c.buyPrice,
                bandA: c.bandA,
                bandB: c.bandB,
                bandC: c.bandC
              };
            });
    
            // create a new "State" object without mutating 
            // the original State object. 
            const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
              products: newProducts
            });
    
            // store the new state object in the component's state
            this.setState(newState);
            

          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
        
      }

      
    
      componentWillUnmount() {

        if (this._asyncRequest) {
       
             this._asyncRequest.cancel();
          }
          
       
 
        
    }
     

  

    render() {
 
        // list of products
        var filteredProducts = this.state.products;
   
 
        return (
            <div className='overflow-hidden'>
                <TopActionsComponent changeAppMode={this.props.changeAppMode} />
 
                <ProductsTable
                    products={filteredProducts}
                    changeAppMode={this.props.changeAppMode}  />
            </div>
        );
    }
    
}
```

Update Product Component:

X

```js
export default class UpdateProductComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            products: [],
            prodName: '',
            description: '',
            buyPrice: 0,
            dutyPrice:  0,
            id:0,
            successCreation: null


        };
    }
     
    // on mount, fetch product data to stored them as this component's state
    componentDidMount() {
         
        // read one product data
        var productId = this.props.productId;
         this.getProduct(productId);

    }

    getProduct(id) {
         
          let data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("userData"));
          this.setState({name:data.userData.name});
        
      
          if (data) {
  
            GetData(`../products/${id}`, 'Bearer ' + data.userData.token)
            .then(response => { 
              
              const product = response;
              this.setState({id: product.id});
              this.setState({prodName: product.prodName});
              this.setState({description: product.description});
              this.setState({buyPrice: product.buyPrice});
 
      
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
          }
          
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            
            const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
                products: null
              });
              this.setState(newState);
            
        }

        // handle name change
        onNameChange = (e) => {
            this.setState({name: e.target.value});
        }
        
        // handle description change
        onDescriptionChange = (e) => {
            var val =e.target.value;

            this.setState({description: val}); 


             
        }
        
        // handle price change
        onPriceChange = (e) => {
            this.setState({buyPrice: e.target.value});
        }

        // handle save changes button clicked

        onSave= (e) => {
 
    // data in the form
        var form_data={
            id:this.state.id,
            description: this.state.description,
            buyPrice: this.state.buyPrice,
            prodName: this.state.prodName
        };

        let data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("userData"));
       

        PostApiData(`../products/${this.state.id}`, 'Bearer ' + data.userData.token,  
        JSON.stringify({
      
            id:this.state.id,
            description: this.state.description,
            buyPrice: this.state.buyPrice,
            prodName: this.state.prodName
        }) , 'PUT'
        )
        .then((result) => {
          
         //let responseJson = result;
         console.log("Successful" + JSON.stringify(result));

         
        });
    

 
    e.preventDefault();
}

        render() {

            return(
                <div>
            {
                this.state.successUpdate === "Product was updated." ?
                    <div className='alert alert-success'>
                        Product was updated.
                    </div>
                : null
            }
 
            {
                this.state.successUpdate === "Unable to update product." ?
                    <div className='alert alert-danger'>
                        Unable to update product. Please try again.
                    </div>
                : null
            }
 
            <a href=''
                onClick={() => this.props.changeAppMode('read', this.state.id)}
                className='btn btn-primary margin-bottom-1em'
                
                >
                Read Products..
            </a>
 
            <form onSubmit={this.onSave}>
                <table className='table table-bordered table-hover'>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                className='form-control'
                                value={this.state.prodName}
                                required
                                onChange={this.onNameChange} />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
 
                    <tr>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea
                                type='text'
                                className='form-control'
                                required
                                value={this.state.description}
                                onChange={this.onDescriptionChange.bind(this)}></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
 
                    <tr>
                        <td>Price ($)</td>
                        <td>
                            <input
                                type='number'
                                step="0.01"
                                className='form-control'
                                value={this.state.buyPrice}
                                required
                                onChange={this.onPriceChange}/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                  
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <button
                                className='btn btn-primary'
                                onClick={this.onSave}>Save Changes</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
            );
        }
```

The update product page shows the correct data once save and updates to the db correctly. Once I navigate back to the products page it shows the old values.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: I believe you've posted the same component twice.

Comment: cheers... edited it now.